# Resource Based Policy In Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a lambda which I have created using serverless framework. I want it to be invoked through cloudwatch logs. For this, I need to create a resource based policy in my AWS lambda. Since the cloudwatch logs which are invoking my lambda are created on the fly I can't use resource name explicitly in [events](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cloudwatch-log/). I wanted to use regex but apparently lambda updation/creation fails with the error below.

```
Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\.\-_/#A-Za-z0-9]+ (Service: AWSLogs; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterExceptio
```

I wanted to know if I can create lambda invocation policy for log group with regex. I tried using resourcePolicy too but it doesn't work. I have two questions which can help me move ahead and was looking for the help.

1. What is the difference between [events](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cloudwatch-log/) and [resourcePolicy](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#resource-policy) in serverless ?
2. Any code pointers which can help me create a resource based policy on the lambda. Image of the policy details I want to create is below.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Events define what will be the trigger for function - a request to an HTTP endpoint, a new message in SNS, etc. Resource policy allows to control what can or cannot invoke HTTP endpoint (essentially a policy in API Gateway).

In serverless.js to define a function that triggered by a new log messages in CW Log Group all you need is this:

```yaml
functions:
    myFunctionName:
        handler: myHandler
        events:
            - cloudwatchLog: /myLog/GroupName
```

Comment: Tried this already. It didn't work because you can't put regex expressions here.

Comment: You cannot use regex pattern in `LogGroupName` of `AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter` [1] (this is what generated by serverless.js during deploy).  

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-subscriptionfilter.html